# Separating git subproject from two branches

Tags: git

I would like to split a git repository into two, e.g. "project" and "project/tools". There are currently two branches ("master" for project, "tools" for project/tools) that reflect this development (specific changes in both):

```
    repo(s)        branch(es)
    -------------  -------------
now project        master, tools
                      |       |
new project        master     |
    tools          master  <--+
```

Could I just delete/move the respective files in their respective branches (e.g. delete "tools" dir in "master" branch and everything except "tools" in "tools" branch) and then somehow create independent repositories from these two branches (duplicate, delete the other branch, rename branch and repository)?

Are there commands that automate this directly ([git-subtree split](https://ariya.io/2014/07/extracting-parts-of-git-repository-and-keeping-the-history) or git [filter-branch](https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/))?

Or should I merge the branches first and then proceed as described in either of the links above ([1](https://ariya.io/2014/07/extracting-parts-of-git-repository-and-keeping-the-history),[2](https://help.github.com/articles/splitting-a-subfolder-out-into-a-new-repository/)).

Comment: In the meantime, I have merged the branches, cloned "project" to "tools" and used the filter-branch method described in [2] to extract "tools". In "project" I just have removed the subdirectory "tools".

Answer (score 1):

If each of the branches only touched the files you are concerned about, one simple way to do this might just be to create two clones of your original repo, one for each branch, using `git clone --single-branch --branch [master/tools]`

```
   --[no-]single-branch
       Clone only the history leading to the tip of a single branch, either specified by the --branch option or the primary
       branch remote's HEAD points at. When creating a shallow clone with the --depth option, this is the default, unless
       --no-single-branch is given to fetch the histories near the tips of all branches. Further fetches into the resulting
       repository will only update the remote-tracking branch for the branch this option was used for the initial cloning. If
       the HEAD at the remote did not point at any branch when --single-branch clone was made, no remote-tracking branch is
       created.
```

Comment: Thanks for this, however I branched "tools" only recently from "master", so I think their history is pretty much the same. But this brings up other questions, as now I really don't need all the history. I will give this a try soon. Docs: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#_options

Comment: You could start out by doing above followed by a filter-branch operation to remove the crap that you dont want in each of the branches, although that does rewrite history (if that is of concern).